# C# - Get the date of last job execution by created date and UNIX Cron expression

Tags: c#, .net, cron

is there a way in C# (.NET Core) to get the DateTime of the last job execution, if I know the CreatedDate of job (or the first run of Job) and the UNIX cron expression?

I'm using Cronos library to get the next time execution by

```
CrontabSchedule.Parse("0 * * * *").GetNextOccurrence(DateTime.Now)
```

But I just can't find a way to get the previous time/last execution time.

For an explanation of using, I got a local DB that stores Linux crontab lines with information about DateTime of creating cronjob and the UNIX cron expression.
In the code, I want to recalculate this information to get next time of execution (this is done), and last time of execution.

Thanks

Comment: Looking through the Cronos code, it doesn't look like there is a built in solution to get the last previous execution time. However, it looks like you could use "GetOccurences" https://github.com/HangfireIO/Cronos/blob/08adc4bd2b7b7af75f2526ea3b99890e96e80e49/src/Cronos/CronExpression.cs#L266 to iterate through time ranges in the past until you find some occurence.

Comment: I maybe find some solution here, but its not optional for me
https://github.com/atifaziz/NCrontab/issues/15